# How to display the comment only once but display all images from mysql in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I want to display the comment only once e.g (testsetest) with the related images (which has the same imagesid by connecting the two tables).

Example (that I want to achieve): 
comment: fool with images: name1, name 2

### [Caption of the wrong output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEIoU.png)

The database structure

> posts:

```
| commentid |  comment  | iamgesid |
------------------------------------
|     1     |   fool    |   5557   |
|     2     |  fool2    |   5585   |
------------------------------------
```

> multiple_image:

```
| id |  image  | imagesid |
---------------------------
| 1  |  name1  |    5557  |
| 2  |  name2  |    5557  |
| 3  |  name3  |    5585  |
---------------------------
```

This is my current code:

```
$sql = "SELECT image, posts.imagesid, multiple_image.imagesid, comment
        FROM multiple_image JOIN posts ON (multiple_image.imagesid=posts.imagesid)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . $conn->error);
}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo $row['comment'];
$imgs= "<div id='img_div'><img width='' src='upload/".$row['image']."' ></div>";
echo $imgs;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to control break the result and order by the commentid

Please see the updated code.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
          image, 
          posts.imagesid, 
          multiple_image.imagesid, 
          comment
        FROM
           multiple_image 
        JOIN posts ON (multiple_image.imagesid=posts.imagesid)
        ORDER BY 
           commentid
";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . $conn->error);
}


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    $comment = '';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if($comment != $row['comment']){
         echo $row['comment'];
         $comment = $row['comment'];
      }

        $imgs= "<div id='img_div'><img width='' src='upload/".$row['image']."' ></div>";
        echo $imgs;
    }
}
```

Comment: that still doesn't do what I want.

Comment: can you explain a little more ?

Comment: I try to be more clear. I want to connect the imagesid between the two tables and only display the comment only once with the related images which can be more than one. I hope it is cleared up a bit more.

Comment: ok and my example does not fit because? It is only printing one comment per group of images of the same imagesid.?

Comment: Oh, pardon me, it looks like it does the job

Comment: that's good, if it comply with your request please mark it as answered. thanks!

Comment: [Can you please help me out on this as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843838/how-to-display-all-related-images-with-a-comment-in-separated-div-and-repeat-the)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flag and check if it is 0. If it is 0 then you can show comment else you dont need to show comment. Check below code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    $loop = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($loop == 0) {            
            echo $row['comment'];
        }
        $imgs = "<div id='img_div'><img width='' src='upload/" . $row['image'] . "' ></div>";
        echo $imgs;
        $loop++;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: this ia goint to print the comment once, not once per group.

Comment: I have changed `if ($loop == 0)` to `if ($loop == 1)` and it is showing the comment only once. Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help out:

```
$sql    = "SELECT 
          image, 
          posts.imagesid, 
          multiple_image.imagesid, 
          comment
        FROM
           multiple_image 
        JOIN posts ON (multiple_image.imagesid=posts.imagesid)
        ORDER BY 
           commentid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . $conn->error);
}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $comment = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // check imagesid is not exist in array
        if (in_array($row['imagesid'], $comment) == false) {
            echo $row['comment'];
            $comment[] = $row['imagesid'];
        }
        $imgs = "<div id='img_div'><img width='' src='upload/" . $row['image'] . "' ></div>";
        echo $imgs;
    }
}
```

Comment: also we can use like this:if (!in_array($row['imagesid'], $comment)) {
            echo $row['comment'];
            $comment[] = $row['imagesid'];
        }